# Error creating a duplicate table in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I wanted to create the copy of a table using the following sql command in oracle:

```
create table table_backup as select * from paper_search;
```

I encountered the error like this

```
 [Err] ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 8192 in tablespace
```

Since the table paper_search is 20GB of size. I googled and found increasing the TEMP memory size in oracle but I have no idea how to solve this any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why you need TEMP space for that insert. Paper_Search isn't a table but a view? can you post it?

Comment: what id the amount of freespace you have in your default tablespace (the TS where that table will be getting created)? do you have enough room in there to hold the new table. you can specify the tablespace by putting `create table table_backup tablespace XXX as select * from paper_search`

Comment: I don't understannd. Why is _TEMP_ segment involved and not a normal segment in the tablespaces of table table_backup? With a standard insert we may write some Undo information, some redo logs and main information in the target tabespace. Where is used TEMP? Or why a TEMP segment. Something I'm missing...

Comment: @FlorinGhita: My guess is that the result of the select needs TEMP space, before it's "moved" to the actual tablespace. Maybe `paper_serach` is indeed a view using joins and group by (which would need temp space)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Maybe I don't know the internals of CTAS, but select * from paper_search would read from disk and bring blocks into SGA(Database Buffer Cache) and then the insert would create extents in the segment of target table, with the data from Buffer Cache. There's no need to move something. Even on updates, much less on inserts.

Comment: @FlorinGhita: as I said: this *could* be the case if `paper_search` is actually a view that contains joins and group by. If those get big enough they will use temp space (e.g. a large hash join, or hash group by).

Comment: "For an explanation of the behavior you see in a CTAS take a look at number 4 in Metalink note 181132.1, which says: “The CTAS creates a data segment in the target tablespace and marks this segment as temporary in dictionary. On completion, the dictionary type is changed from temporary to table.” http://coskan.wordpress.com/2007/12/05/temp-segments-in-normal-datafile-ora-1652/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find enough space for your temp segment (see Orangecrush's answer), you may want to consider creating the table and populating it in separate steps - e.g.

```
create table table_backup as select * from paper_search where 1=0;
```

then

```
insert into table_backup select * from paper_search where id between :1 and :2;
```

in a loop with suitable ranges for id, committing between each batch (so that you don't need so much temp space).

This is just a rough solution *and may not be feasible depending on your requirements* (e.g. whether it should take into account concurrent inserts/updates/deletes on the table while your batch job is running).

Answer (score 1):

Your temp tablespace is full. Extend it and then create the table.

Syntax:

```
ALTER tablespace TEMP add datafile '<path>/temp1.dbf' size 1500M
```

Change the path, name and size as required.